# C++ Class Variable Declared in abc.h not recognized in abc.cpp

Tags: arrays, class, oop, c++11, struct

I have this problem

```
"abc.h"

Class abc{
Private:    

  bool ** xyz;

Public:
abc * fun();
}

"abc.cpp"

#include "abc.h"

abc abc::*fun(){
xyz=new bool*[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    xyz[i]= new bool[10];
    }
}
```

I am getting **xyz undeclared identifier**. Kindly help me out in this. I have also tried

```
abc::xyz=new bool*[10];
```

its also not working

Comment: you din not included your abc.h file into abc.cpp file.Please include it.

Comment: Is "include" section properly added? Class is written uppercase.  abc is not a static field, but object field. Please post whole code

Comment: By the way... It is better to not define class inside .h file you can easly get into trouble. .h is better for declaration (without class body, declaration finishes after class name by ;)

Comment: @Astro i have included #include "abc.h" in my cpp file.

Comment: @Max can you provide some example how to do that..

Comment: Are you using Dev-C++.??

Comment: **The code you show could not possible give the error message you posted.**

Comment: Then what error message it should give. Kindly elaborate your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The code you show could not possible give the error message you posted.**

---

Put exactly this into the header file:

```
class abc {
  public:
    abc* fun();
  private:    
    bool ** xyz;
};
```

Put exactly this into the source file:

```
#include "abc.h"

abc* abc::fun() {
  xyz=new bool*[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    xyz[i]= new bool[10];
  }
  return this; // What would you like to return???
}
```

This has to compile at least.

---

I noticed a few strange things in the code you posted. The keywords `class`, `public` and `private` do **not** start with a capital letter.

The class declaration is followed by a `;`.

Although `abc abc::*fun()` could exist, I am almost sure you meant `abc* abc::fun()`.

`abc::fun()` does not return anything.

Comment: I know about Keywords and about ;. These are not the reasons i was getting error :) I want to return the pointer of the abc class.

Comment: @user1930448 Well, in that case return `this` as you see it in the code.

Comment: I have declared a private int num variable and i am modifying its value in fun. I want to use this variable num value again in other function. Is this possible? Because i am getting garbage value. The value is deleted automaticaly on function exit i think...

Comment: @user1930448 Please post a new question with your code. It's hard to tell, and comments are not appropriate for this kind of debugging. Or even better, post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/problem-using-private-int-data-variable

Comment: OK, let's hope someone will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to see the definition of type `abc` and to do that you need to include the header which defines it in the cpp file.

**"abc.h"**

```
class abc{
bool ** xyz;
void fun();
};
```

**"abc.cpp"**

```
#include "abc.h"         <--------------This!
void abc::fun(){
**xyz=new bool [10];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
abc abc::*fun()
```

Should be this:

```
abc * abc::fun()
```